# Unable to read excel after updation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, apache-poi

I am learning selenium webdriver and trying to read the excel using Apache POI lib with below snippet. It has run successfully but after updating the excel file. It does not read updated values or excel data. Always print previous content.

public org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet;

```
public static FileInputStream ReadExcel;

public void read_excel(String excel_file_path, String DataSheetName) throws Exception, IOException

{
    try
    {

    ReadExcel=new FileInputStream(new File(excel_file_path));

        Workbook wp=WorkbookFactory.create(ReadExcel);
        sheet=wp.getSheet(DataSheetName);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator=sheet.rowIterator();

        while(rowIterator.hasNext())
        {

            Row row=rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();

            while(cellIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                String cellData=cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(cellData);
            }

        }
        ReadExcel.close();

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the updates made in excel sheet ? try using the previous version of file format with excel 97-2003 workbook another solution is the path for the excel file has not been modified thus it is not using the newer file. Also check the file name as you have used it as string here.

Below is the sample TC for Excel file reading :

```
package excelExportAndFileIO;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class aafileread {



    public void readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws IOException{

    //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file

    File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);

    //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    Workbook FILENAME = null;


    String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

    //Check condition if the file is xlsx file

    if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){

    //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

    filename = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    }

    //Check condition if the file is xls file

    else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){

        //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

        Filename = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    }

    //Read sheet inside the workbook by its name

    Sheet Sheetname = Filename.getSheet(sheetName);

    //Find number of rows in excel file

    int rowCount = sheetname.getLastRowNum()-sheetname.getFirstRowNum();

    //Create a loop over all the rows of excel file to read it

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {

        Row row = sheetname.getRow(i);

        //Create a loop to print cell values in a row

        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {

            //Print excel data in console

            System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");

        }

        System.out.println();

    }



    }



    //Main function is calling readExcel function to read data from excel file

    public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException{

    //Create a class

    FilenameFile objExcelFile = new FilenameFile();

    //Prepare the path of excel file

    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\excelExportAndFileIO";

    //Call read file method of the class to read data

    objExcelFile.readExcel(filePath,"Filename.xlsx","Filename");

    }

}
```